# Close session without writing or destroying it

Tags: php, session

Is there a way to close a PHP session without either writing or destroying it? Am I missing something or are there just two functions (`session_write_close()` and `session_destroy()`) which reset `session_status()` to `PHP_SESSION_NONE`? In other words, if I have an open session, can I simply close it without affecting the external session data, so it can be reloaded again.

Comment: There is no need to do that. If you don't want the session "to be enabled" - simply don't use it.

Comment: Thank you the knight of the logical thinking. If I didn't want to use it in first place, I'd have hardly gotten to the stage of asking about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some months later after raising an [issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67421) the two new methods are now available in PHP 5.6, but the documentation arrived only with 5.6.2.

- `session_abort()` – Discard session array changes and finish session, see the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-abort.php).
- `session_reset()` – Re-initialize session array with original values, see the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-reset.php).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by `$_SESSION = null`. The session is unavailable but the data remains (does not get deleted).

Consider you have data in the session:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(); // get a fresh id
echo session_id();

$_SESSION['test'] = '12345';

print_r($_SESSION); // echoes the data in the session
```

Data: `test|s:5:"12345";`

Then in the next request:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id() . "<br>"; //  echoes the same id as of the last request

$_SESSION = null;

print_r($_SESSION); // echoes nothing

echo "<br>";

echo session_status(); // echoes 2 (PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
```

Data still the same: `test|s:5:"12345";`

(`php-fpm 5.4.29, most recent nginx, memcached as session handler`).

Well the data still can be written through `$_SESSION['whatever'] = ...` but not read. I'm not sure whether this is a good solution but I have to admit I still don't understand why or whatfor you need this.

As an alternative, you could implement a wrapper class for the session with a property `$this->active = true; // or false`:

```
class MySessionWrapper {
    protected $active;
    protected $data;
    // getter setter for $this->active and $this->data ...

    public function getData($var) {
        if ($this->active !== true) {
            throw new Exception('session disabled');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into. The first part is not really a solution – session_status remains active. The second solution is what I currently have, but it kind of implies reinventing the wheel a little. I need this for a test suite, I need to to reload current session data after running an isolated php command, which often modifies it. There are a few workarounds but they all hacky and often lead to undesirable results when used with native session functions.

Comment: @IanBytchek Ok I understand your case now. Unfortunately I don't imagine a better solution tho. Good luck with it :)

Comment: Appreciate you input :)

Comment: Please update your question on why you want to reset the session.

Comment: When you open a PHP session a lock is created, so all session-based PHP scripts are forced to execute synchronously, defeating the benefits of asynchronous calls. You can see this in websites that seem to hang on load, where every page element is served via a php script that becomes serialized due to session access. Best practice would be to only session_start if needed and close access to that session ASAP to avoid queuing of web requests.